# Use COUNTIFS efficiently to return data for different criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am counting the number of responses for the the different type of responses (`Strongly Agree`, `Agree`, `Disagree`) for each class (class 1, class 2):

[image: Image of my problem]

I am able to do a COUNTIFS for each different subject (sub 1, sub 2). Eg, for sub 1, to count the number of students from [Class 1] with responses `Strongly Agree`. I use the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,$A10,$B$2:$B$5,B$9)
```

However, this means I need to change the reference column for each subject.

Is there a more efficient way for doing it such that if I change the subject (cell A8), eg from sub 1 to sub 2, the statistic will change accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `MATCH` to return the column number of the subject, and then use `ADDRESS` and `INDIRECT` to make it into an address for `COUNTIFS` to act upon. Something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5, $A10, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, MATCH($A$8, $A$1:$C$1, 0))&":"&ADDRESS(5, MATCH($A$8, $A$1:$C$1, 0))), B$9)
```

Where the `MATCH($A$8...)` refers to the subject cell, and the `ADDRESS(2..` and `ADDRESS(5..` are the top and bottom rows of the list that you want to count over.

The alternative to this would be to add an additional subject column and only have a single column that you want to count over. This would only require modification of the formula you posted by adding an additional criteria.

Comment: Hi mike7mike, it works! 
Thanks so much. For the Address(2.. and Address(5.., how can it be used to reference to another worksheet? In my case, the name of reference worksheet is "Raw"

When I tried Address (Raw!2..., excel said there is an error in formula
When I tried Address (Raw!2:2...,I get [#value!]

Comment: Hi @KinChuahChan, sorry for the delay in response. You need to insert the sheet name at the before the address statment i.e. INDIRECT("Raw!"&ADDRESS(...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [unpivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120) then constructing a new PT from the resulting table with Column above Row for ROWS and Count of Value for VALUES:

[image: SO33098690 example]

Comment: Hi pnuts,
Thanks for tidying up my question and providing the solution. Did not try it out as I am unfamiliar with pivot table. In any case, appreciate your response!